# Reading asynchronous pipe - loosing data

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, asynchronous, pipe

I want to read data from a pipe. The reads must not block the main thread (so everything is in a separate thread), and it must be cancellable (so I use overlapped IO with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag)

This following code is simplified, but I only removed error checking :

```
pipe = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\pipename", PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED , 0, 1, 1024, 1024, 1000, NULL);

while (1) {
  // wait for either new data, or cancellation
  DWORD wait = WaitForMultipleObjects(2,events,FALSE,INFINITE);

  // Assume "new data event" and no error

  GetOverlappedResult(pipe,&overlap,&unused,FALSE); // always succeeds
  ReadFile(pipe,outputbuffer,neededsize,outputsize, &overlap); // sometimes says ERROR_IO_PENDING via GetLastError()
}
```

- The first buffers are received correctly.
- No data is sent for a few seconds
- This seems to signal the event. No data is read (*none was sent*!), and `ReadFile()` sets `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.
- Another set of data is sent
- `ReadFile` looses some of the new data.

To be be precise, the last `ReadFile()` looses as much data as I requested in the *previous* `ReadFile()`.

What do I do wrong?

[Obligatory reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa365603(v=vs.85).aspx)

EDIT - Correct way, again without error checking :

```
BOOL res = ReadFile(...as before...);
if(res)
    return; //success, reading was instantaneous, there was already data.
//GetLastError() is supposed to be ERROR_IO_PENDING here
wait = WaitForMultipleObjects(2,events,FALSE,INFINITE);
// Assume "new data event" and no error
res = GetOverlappedResult(pipe, &overlap, &cbRet, FALSE);
// Now the buffer you gave to ReadFile has its cbRet first bytes filled.
```

Comment: Excelent way to ask a question. I wish there were more questions like this. Sadly I have no Idea of the API you're using, but I upvoted the question hoping it gets more attention.

Comment: Where do you process the asynchronous result from the ReadFile call that returned ERROR_IO_PENDING? ERROR_IO_PENDING isn't a failure, it means the data will be delivered asynchronously.

Comment: Please show how you create the pipe.  (So that, among other things, we can see whether it is in message mode or in stream mode.)

Comment: @iharob it is regular plain ol' Win32.

Comment: I have replaced [windows] with the more specific [winapi], as this question seems specific to Windows API behavior.

Comment: When you say "ReadFile() sets ERROR_IO_PENDING", is it actually returning FALSE? It's a common mistake to call `GetLastError()` when a function hasn't actually failed, and you've stripped out all your error checking code so we can't tell.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more of the code, but it looks like you're doing it back to front, i.e., waiting for an event and then issuing the read request, as if you were using select().  Windows asynchronous I/O works the other way around, i.e., you issue the read request, then wait for the event saying it completed.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Please put your comment as an answer. Upvotes will ensue =) Thanks !!!!

Comment: I think that's a true duplicate - the ReadFile loop looks very much the same as yours - but if the community disagrees with me then I'll post an answer here as well, though it will look very much like the existing one. :-)